# Como configurar o .htaccess para que aceite hífen na URL?

Tags: htaccess, url-rewrite, url-amigável

Estou personalizando as URLs do meu site, mas o `.htaccess` não aceita URLs com hífens, por exemplo:

```
postagem/1/criando-efeito-fadeout-com-javascript
```

Quando escrevo o título sem os hífens funciona, mas com eles não, por quê? Como eu resolvo isso?

Minha regra do `.htaccess` está escrita da seguinte forma:

```apache
RewriteRule ^postagem/([0-9]+)(/([a-z]+)/)?$ ler.php?post=$1&titulo=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sua expressão regular contém o trecho `[a-z]`, definindo que somente letras são aceitas.

Adicione o hífen da seguinte forma: `[a-z\-]`. Você fica com a expressão:

```apache
RewriteRule ^postagem/([0-9]+)(/([a-z\-]+)/)?$ ler.php?post=$1&titulo=$2 [NC,L]
```

Opcionalmente, você poderia incluir números, assim:

```apache
RewriteRule ^postagem/([0-9]+)(/([a-z0-9\-]+)/)?$ ler.php?post=$1&titulo=$2 [NC,L]
```

Nota: como o hífen é um caractere especial para a expressão regular, eu adicionei uma barra (\) de *escape*.

Comment: acho que faltou o escape no escape pra aparecer na resposta :)

Comment: @Bacco Não sabia que a barra invertida era um caractere especial!

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, eu também não, mas que é irônico, é :)